# define with spring the expireAfter of a mongo document

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I want to define the expireAfter delay of my mongoDocument in my application.yml, but I'm not sure how to do it.
I've try this, but it don't work because it's not a spring bean

```
@Document(collection = "myDoc")
class MyDocDocument{
    @Indexed(expireAfter = "#{mongo.expirationDelay}")
    val endOfLastJourneyDate: OffsetDateTime,
}
```

any idea?

Comment: Document is not a spring bean and not be managed by spring bean. You can inject the value into service and pass it to document in the saving method.